# WPF: Using a Usercontrol multiple times to show data about different employees

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, observablecollection

I'm kinda new to this WPF stuff and would like some help.

I have a DataGrid that is filled with info about employees from a observablecollection, like name, adress etc. With this I am trying to implement a tabview that shows multiple instances of the same usercontrol. This usercontrol will contain info about one employee, a picture etc. So on one tab I have this DataGrid, on the other one I would like to have a usercontrol multiple times containing one employee each from the datagrid.

I can't wrap my head around how to "loop" out the same usercontrol next to each other multiple times, each one containing a different employee from the DataGrid.

Comment: Do you need to open such usercontrols on the selection from datagrid, or do you need to load all the rows of this datagrid as soon as it is available?

Comment: Also, if you like, i would suggest you to check [RowDetails](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/details-row/). It's a nice way to display extra info for your datagrid, and allow you to build a template containing anything you like (you can add extra info for the employees, like picture, and also add functionalities with buttons, textboxes or anything you would like)

Comment: Along with the RowDetails already mentioned by Daniele, consider using a templated tooltip.

Comment: The usercontrols is not based on selection so far, I would just like to load one row in one usercontrol, and repeat for entire datagrid. Ok, I will check on RowDetails and tooltip, thanks